# Google Tag Manager Implementation

Tags: ios, swift3, google-tag-manager

I'm integrating Google Tag Manager for my iOS Application. I downloaded all the required file which are : `TAGManager.h`, `TAGContainer.h`, `TAGContainerOpener.h`, `TAGDataLayer.h`, `TAGLogger.h`

When I added these in my project, the code compiles but when it starts linking then it throws error as below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"OBJC_CLASS$_TAGContainerOpener", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added below code in AppDelegate.swift file:

```
TAGContainerOpener.openContainer(withId: "GTM-PT3L9Z",
tagManager: GTM, openType: kTAGOpenTypePreferFresh,
timeout: nil,
notifier: self)
```

Could anyone please tell me why I get this linking error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might be using an old implementation. The newest version is v5 (Firebase + GTM), here is the [docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/).

Comment: I installed the pod files but I still get the same issue. Please help me

Comment: @XamarinDev Could you be more especific with the error? Ive deal with this implementation on the past and its not easy you need to read step by step everything on the Docs and discard anything you ve done from previous implementations.